# Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING

Tags: php, apache, gzip

I use quickcache from http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickcache to have some dynamic pages cached for some time

In my server [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate

but from quickcache_main.php

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"],'x-gzip') !== false)
```

and

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"],'gzip') !== false) {
```

is invoked I get the title error in error_log. I don't see any problem loading those cached pages from a mysql table or accessing a not cached (or expired) page when the scripts creates the new cached one. I also never saw my tests triggered a new error log like the title. Anyway I see them very frequently listed. What I am missing?

Comment: The `Accept-Encoding:` header isn't there for all requests / clients. When absent: notice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @mario I don't understand this well. Related to the linked question, I had added if(isset... but notices still appeared.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])) {
    ob_start();            
}
elseif (strpos(' ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'x-gzip') == false) {
    if (strpos(' ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') == false) {
        ob_start();
    }
    elseif(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) {
        ob_start();
    }   
}
elseif(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) {
    ob_start();
}
```